# Enclosing Select to use PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have tried a couple of combinations to wrap the last select to use PIVOT with its result

This is the code

```
   DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sqlquery VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT distinct  ',' + QuoteName(idIndice)
                        FROM tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as a FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, '')      

SET @sqlquery = 'WITH TempTable AS 
                ( 
                    select distinct a.id, b.idIndice, b.valor  
                    from tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Documentos as a  
                    join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as b on a.id = b.idDocumento 
                    join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType as c on a.idDocType = c.id
                    join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType_Index as d on c.id = d.docTypeId 
                    where d.docTypeId = 40      
                    and (b.idIndice = 11 AND b.valor = ''11111111'' OR b.idIndice = 12 AND b.valor = ''11111'' ) 
                ) 
                SELECT * FROM TempTable t1 
                         WHERE ((select count(*)          
                         from TempTable t2        
                         where t1.id = t2.id AND t1.valor != t2.valor) = 1)base
                PIVOT 
                (
                    Max(valor)
                    FOR [idIndice] IN (' + @cols + ')
                ) AS finalpivot' 

EXECUTE ( @sqlquery )
```

This of course will not work so do I need to enclose parentheses or somenthing like that to get it done???

Comment: I just need a Ok it is possible or You cannot do that. Google just has nothing related to that. I am inclined to think that is not even possible. I would love to know why so I do not make this mistake again

Comment: What value are you getting for `@cols`?  Also what error message are you getting?  If you can get your `@sqlquery` running outside of an `EXECUTE()` then it should work inside an `EXECUTE()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try replace EXECUTE ( @sqlquery ) on EXEC @sqlquery
```

[more info about EXECUTE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)